# HTML hyperlink that updates a table field in an Access database

Tags: html, vba, ms-access-2010

I have created a hyperlink in an email that opens an access database.

```
<'a href='" & "C:\data.final\databaser\FE\shelfstatus_FE.mdb" & "'>LINK<'/a><'/p>
```

I want to include a statement in the `HTML` hyperlink that updates a table in the access database when the user click on the hyperlink.

similar to

```
"UPDATE date = '2016-03-16' FROM register WHERE number = 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this can't be done with a simple hyperlink directly to the database. One solution would be creating a VBScript or batch file that performs the update...

In example.vbs:

```
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open _
    "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
        "Data Source = C:\data.final\databaser\FE\shelfstatus_FE.mdb"

sql = "UPDATE register SET DateField = #3/16/2016# WHERE number = 1"
rs.Open sql, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

...then hyperlink to that:

```
<'a href='" & "C:\data.final\databaser\FE\example.vbs" & "'>LINK<'/a><'/p>
```